# Dataloss error during usign trained data

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, checkpoint

I tried to test trained data.

---

```
!/usr/bin/env python

Copyright (c) 2016 Artsiom Sanakoyeu

from __future__ import division
from chainer import iterators
import cmd_options
import dataset
import os
import time
import regressionnet
import tensorflow as tf
import copy
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import math
import pprint
import datetime

from regressionnet import evaluate_pcp, create_sumamry


def evaluate(net, pose_loss_op, test_iterator, summary_writer,                      tag='test/pose_loss'):
 test_it = copy.copy(test_iterator)
total_loss = 0.0
cnt = 0
num_batches = int(math.ceil(len(test_it.dataset) / test_it.batch_size))
print len(test_it.dataset)
for batch in tqdm(test_it, total=num_batches):
    feed_dict = regressionnet.fill_joint_feed_dict(net,
                                                   regressionnet.batch2feeds(batch)[:3],
                                                   conv_lr=0.0,
                                                   fc_lr=0.0,
                                                   phase='test')
    global_step, loss_value = net.sess.run([net.global_iter_counter, pose_loss_op],
                                           feed_dict=feed_dict)
    total_loss += loss_value * len(batch)
    cnt += len(batch)
avg_loss = total_loss / len(test_it.dataset)
print 'Step {} {} = {:.3f}'.format(global_step, tag, avg_loss)
summary_writer.add_summary(create_sumamry(tag, avg_loss),
                           global_step=global_step)
assert cnt == 1000, 'cnt = {}'.format(cnt)


def train_loop(net, saver, loss_op, pose_loss_op, train_op, dataset_name,     train_iterator, test_iterator,
           val_iterator=None,
           max_iter=None,
           test_step=None,
           snapshot_step=None,
           log_step=1,
           batch_size=None,
           conv_lr=None,
           fc_lr=None,
           fix_conv_iter=None,
           output_dir='results',
           ):

summary_step = 50

with net.graph.as_default():
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(output_dir, net.sess.graph)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    fc_train_op = net.graph.get_operation_by_name('fc_train_op')
global_step = None

for step in xrange(max_iter + 1):

    # test, snapshot
    if step % test_step == 0 or step + 1 == max_iter or step == fix_conv_iter:
        global_step = net.sess.run(net.global_iter_counter)
        evaluate_pcp(net, pose_loss_op, test_iterator, summary_writer,
                     dataset_name=dataset_name,
                     tag_prefix='test')
        if val_iterator is not None:
            evaluate_pcp(net, pose_loss_op, val_iterator, summary_writer,
                         dataset_name=dataset_name,
                         tag_prefix='val')

    if step % snapshot_step == 0 and step > 1:
        checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(output_dir, 'checkpoint')
        assert global_step is not None
        saver.save(net.sess, checkpoint_prefix, global_step=global_step)
    if step == max_iter:
        break

    # training
    start_time = time.time()
    feed_dict = regressionnet.fill_joint_feed_dict(net,
                                                   regressionnet.batch2feeds(train_iterator.next())[:3],
                                                   conv_lr=conv_lr,
                                                   fc_lr=fc_lr,
                                                   phase='train')
    if step < fix_conv_iter:
        feed_dict['lr/conv_lr:0'] = 0.0

    if step < fix_conv_iter:
        cur_train_op = fc_train_op
    else:
        cur_train_op = train_op

    if step % summary_step == 0:
        global_step, summary_str, _, loss_value = net.sess.run(
            [net.global_iter_counter,
             summary_op,
             cur_train_op,
             pose_loss_op],
            feed_dict=feed_dict)
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=global_step)
    else:
        global_step, _, loss_value = net.sess.run(
            [net.global_iter_counter, cur_train_op, pose_loss_op],
            feed_dict=feed_dict)

    duration = time.time() - start_time

    if step % log_step == 0 or step + 1 == max_iter:
        print('Step %d: train/pose_loss = %.2f (%.3f s, %.2f im/s)'
              % (global_step, loss_value, duration,
                 batch_size // duration))


def main(argv):
"""
Run training of the Deeppose stg-1
"""
args = cmd_options.get_arguments(argv)
if not os.path.exists(args.o_dir):
    os.makedirs(args.o_dir)
suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
with open(os.path.join(args.o_dir, 'params.dump_{}.txt'.format(suffix)), 'w') as f:
    f.write('{}\n'.format(pprint.pformat(args)))

net, loss_op, pose_loss_op, train_op = regressionnet.create_regression_net(
    n_joints=args.n_joints,
    init_snapshot_path=args.snapshot,
    is_resume=args.resume,
    reset_iter_counter=args.reset_iter_counter,
    reset_moving_averages=args.reset_moving_averages,
    optimizer_type=args.optimizer,
    gpu_memory_fraction=0.32,  # Set how much GPU memory to reserve for the network
    net_type=args.net_type)
with net.graph.as_default():
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

print 'args.resume: {}\nargs.snapshot: {}'.format(args.resume, args.snapshot)
bbox_extension_range = (args.bbox_extension_min, args.bbox_extension_max)
if bbox_extension_range[0] is None or bbox_extension_range[1] is None:
    bbox_extension_range = None
    test_bbox_extension_range = None
else:
    test_bbox_extension_range = (bbox_extension_range[1], bbox_extension_range[1])

train_dataset = dataset.PoseDataset(
    args.train_csv_fn, args.img_path_prefix, args.im_size,
    fliplr=args.fliplr,
    rotate=args.rotate,
    rotate_range=args.rotate_range,
    shift=args.shift,
    bbox_extension_range=bbox_extension_range,
    min_dim=args.min_dim,
    coord_normalize=args.coord_normalize,
    gcn=args.gcn,
    fname_index=args.fname_index,
    joint_index=args.joint_index,
    symmetric_joints=args.symmetric_joints,
    ignore_label=args.ignore_label,
    should_downscale_images=args.should_downscale_images,
    downscale_height=args.downscale_height
)
test_dataset = dataset.PoseDataset(
    args.test_csv_fn, args.img_path_prefix, args.im_size,
    fliplr=False, rotate=False,
    shift=None,
    bbox_extension_range=test_bbox_extension_range,
    coord_normalize=args.coord_normalize,
    gcn=args.gcn,
    fname_index=args.fname_index,
    joint_index=args.joint_index,
    symmetric_joints=args.symmetric_joints,
    ignore_label=args.ignore_label,
    should_return_bbox=True,
    should_downscale_images=args.should_downscale_images,
    downscale_height=args.downscale_height
)

np.random.seed(args.seed)
train_iterator = iterators.MultiprocessIterator(train_dataset, args.batch_size,
                                                n_processes=args.workers, n_prefetch=3)
test_iterator = iterators.MultiprocessIterator(
    test_dataset, args.batch_size,
    repeat=False, shuffle=False,
    n_processes=1, n_prefetch=1)

val_iterator = None
if args.val_csv_fn is not None and args.val_csv_fn != '':
    small_train_dataset = dataset.PoseDataset(
        args.val_csv_fn,
        args.img_path_prefix, args.im_size,
        fliplr=False, rotate=False,
        shift=None,
        bbox_extension_range=test_bbox_extension_range,
        coord_normalize=args.coord_normalize,
        gcn=args.gcn,
        fname_index=args.fname_index,
        joint_index=args.joint_index,
        symmetric_joints=args.symmetric_joints,
        ignore_label=args.ignore_label,
        should_return_bbox=True,
        should_downscale_images=args.should_downscale_images,
        downscale_height=args.downscale_height
    )
    val_iterator = iterators.MultiprocessIterator(
        small_train_dataset, args.batch_size,
        repeat=False, shuffle=False,
        n_processes=1, n_prefetch=1)

train_loop(net, saver, loss_op, pose_loss_op, train_op, args.dataset_name,
           train_iterator, test_iterator,
           val_iterator=val_iterator,
           max_iter=args.max_iter,
           test_step=args.test_step,
           log_step=args.log_step,
           snapshot_step=args.snapshot_step,
           batch_size=args.batch_size,
           conv_lr=args.conv_lr,
           fc_lr=args.fc_lr,
           fix_conv_iter=args.fix_conv_iter,
           output_dir=args.o_dir
           )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

---

This is code what I used.
I traind it about 370000 iteration and I tried to test trained data.

But it shows this messages

Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a     different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
Traceback (most recent call last):

DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file out/lsp_alexnet_imagenet_small/checkpoint-370000.data-00000-of-00001: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read [How to ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) See if you can clean up the formatting and remove abundant code/logging.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show more of the traceback, to make it easier to pinpoint which part of the code is causing the error.